# Selenium Customise Xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch all the Elements from the page using driver.findElements(By.xpath....

In a Page we have the Xpath produced randomly as shown below:

```
 //*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_dataListSessionTime_lblCinemasName_0']/span
 //*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_dataListSessionTime_lblCinemasName_1']/span
 //*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_dataListSessionTime_lblCinemasName_2']/span
```

and so on..

I need to Count number of such Elements present on a Page.

I am trying to use Xpath / code as shown below.

Using *= in xpath; represent Start with character.

```java
String MovieCinemas=//*[@id*='ContentPlaceHolder1_dataListSessionTime_lblCinemasName_
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
System.out.println("Number of Elements Found: " + elements.size());
```

I am unable to Produce the count of the elements.
Also, throws an exception of Unable to Find the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `starts-with()` function in your XPath instead :

```java
String xpath = "//*[starts-with(@id,'ContentPlaceHolder1_dataListSessionTime_lblCinemasName_')]/span";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
System.out.println("Number of Elements Found: " + elements.size());
```